# two machines two different versions of traceroute

Tags: networking, package-management, traceroute

Ace is `uname -a Linux ace 6.2.0-34-generic #34~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Sep  7 13:12:03 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Nub is `uname -a Linux nub 6.2.0-34-generic #34~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Sep  7 13:12:03 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Ace is

```
traceroute -V
traceroute (GNU inetutils) 2.2
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law
```

Nub is

```
traceroute -V
Modern traceroute for Linux, version 2.1.0
Copyright (c) 2016  Dmitry Butskoy,   License: GPL v2 or any later
```

I have removed and reinstalled the version on Nub several times but no change.  Any Ideas why this has occurred.  I have been trying to gather info on why my network appears slow to load web pages and the conflicting version isn't helping.

Comment: What does `update-alternatives --query traceroute` say on each machine?

Comment: Two different packages offer traceroute: `traceroute` and `inetutils-traceroute`. Try `which traceroute` on both machines, and then `dpkg -S <path>` on the returned path to see which package(s) you are using.

Comment: Just want to say, if you've not tried it before `trippy` is a really good alternative to traceroute, install it with snap if you want. `snap install trippy`, then `sudo trippy google.com` etc.

Comment: steeldriver 
Ace:  Name: traceroute
Link: /usr/bin/traceroute
Best: /usr/bin/inetutils-traceroute
Value: /usr/bin/inetutils-traceroute

Nub: Name: traceroute
Link: /usr/bin/traceroute
Best: /usr/bin/traceroute.db
Value: /usr/bin/traceroute.db

Comment: user535733
traceroute and inetutils-traceroute that appears to be the issue.

Comment: @jamby please [edit] that information into your question